# How to add a new event to Apache Spark Event Log

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

Apache Spark pushes a bunch of information in event logs. How can I push my custom events into this event log?

Does Spark expose any APIs to do this? Or can I extend any existing class to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend "StreamingQueryListener" if you have a stream query and then add it to

```
    spark.streams.addListener(new EventCollector(APP_NAME))
```

where

```
 EventCollector(APP_NAME) extends StreamingQueryListener
```

and write your own methods

```
onQueryStarted
onQueryProgress
onQueryTerminated
```

methods and put custom code in it

Answer (score -1):

Your class can extend `org.apache.spark.Logging` and use the help methods defined there:

```
logInfo("task success") 
logWarn("didn't receive data")
...
```

Note the *warning* on that trait:

> NOTE: DO NOT USE this class outside of Spark. It is intended as an
>   internal utility.  This will likely be changed or removed in future
>   releases.